# HighChart response for time on yaxis and text on xaxis

Tags: highcharts

Looking for combination chart response with time on y-axis text on x-axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Combination chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Amar', 'Kiran', 'Venky']
    },
     yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%H:%M}',
    }
  },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Actual Time',
        data:[Date.parse('2016-10-20 03:14'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 03:30'),Date.parse('2016-10-20 02:15')]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Completed Time',
        data: [Date.parse('2016-10-21 04:14'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 04:32'),Date.parse('2016-10-20 05:32')]
    }]
});
```

Expecting y-axis values are 03:14 ,03:30 etc...
Actual result: Y-axis values are 00:00 , 00:00 etc..

Answer (score 0):

By default, yAxis is starting from 0 threshold. That's why you had only ticks like 00:00. You can change it by setting the `series.threshold` property. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Combination chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Amar', 'Kiran', 'Venky']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%H:%M}',
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Actual Time',
    threshold: Date.parse('2016-10-20 02:00'),
    data: [
     Date.parse('2016-10-20 03:14'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 03:30'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 02:15')]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lo89gwxh/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold

Comment: I am expecting time values of amar has 03:14, kiran has 03:30 , venky has 02:15 on yaxis.But above highchart showing whatever you poseted, amar has time between 21:30 and 22:00, kiran has 22:00,venky has between 20:30 and 21:00.Please give me proper highchart what iam expecting.

Comment: Proper `highcharts` you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bcutjkds/1/

Comment: Thanks,But wrong times are displaying in tooltip.Iam expecting correct values whatever we are displaying on yaxis(Ex: Amar have 03:14,Kiran have 03:30 and venky have 02:15).

Comment: In my previous demo, I can see the correct values in the tooltip. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d4qonckj/. Perhaps you have a different timezone.

Comment: Thanks,But wrong times are displaying in tooltip.Iam expecting correct values whatever we are displaying on yaxis.These values should display in tooltip like Amar have 03:14,Kiran have 03:30 and venky have 02:15.But you are displaying Amar have 21:44 , kiran have 22:00 and venky have 20:45.Give me proper code to display the correct values.

Comment: I've got correct values. Try to change the code responsible for setting a date in the `tooltip.formatter` function.

Comment: I could take multiple yaxis values like below code.Chart is generated properly.

Comment: xAxis: {
     categories: ['Amar', 'Kiran', 'Venky']
   },
 series: [{
     type: 'column',
     name: 'Actual Time',
     threshold: Date.parse('2016-10-20 00:00'),
     data: [
       Date.parse('2016-10-20 03:14'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 03:30'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 02:15')
     ]
   },
   {
     type: 'column',
     name: 'Complete Time',
     threshold: Date.parse('2016-10-20 00:00'),
     data: [
       Date.parse('2016-10-20 04:14'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 04:30'), Date.parse('2016-10-20 02:40')
     ]
   }]

Comment: But how can i also take mulltiple categories values on xaxis.
For example, Iam taking Employee names and Department names.Above response has employee names. I want to generate both names and department names also on xaxis.
Please help..